# Kendo UI Grid update all rows with the selected column value

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I have a ctrl click ability set up for one of my grids where a user can hold ctrl, make a selection from a drop down editor for a cell and I want it to update all the data in the model with that selection, not just that one row.

How do I do this?

```
var R = this;
            $('<input required data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoDropDownList({
                    autoBind: false,
                    dataTextField: "condition",
                    dataValueField: "conditionId",
                    dataSource: config.filters.conditions,
                    close: function () {
                        if (R.ctrlDown) {
                            // Update all rows here somehow....
                            R.data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need something like:

```
// Update all rows here somehow....
R.find(".k-state-selected").each(function (item) {
    R.data("kendoGrid").dataItem(this).value = theSelectedValue;
});
// possibly do something to persist the data here
```

This will iterate through all the selected rows of your grid.

dataItem(HTMLelement) will give you the dataSource item with all your details you'd like to change (.value is an example).

I'm no professional, rather a beginner when it comes to kendo UI, but I've been coding these as well lately, so this piece of code might give you new ideas.
To get into more details, I don't have the time right now and not enough knowledge about the rest of your code ;)